# Passing and returning variables with functions in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, function, variables, return

I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to pass attributes around between functions in a specific way using AS3. How do I change the code below so that the deleteButton function can retrieve the variable myLike from the mySelection function?

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
btnDelete.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, deleteButton);

function keyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent)
{

    var myLike:String;

    if (event.keyCode==49) {
        myLike = "ice cream";
    }
    else if (event.keyCode==50) {
       myLike = "chocolate milk";
    }
    else if (event.keyCode==51) {
       myLike = "cookies";
    }
    else
    {
        myLike = "nothing";
    }

    mySelection(myLike);
}

function mySelection(myLike)
{
    trace("I select " + myLike + ".");
    deleteButton(myLike);
}

function deleteButton(event:MouseEvent, myLike) {
    trace(myLike + "has been deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems you're looking at are:

1. `myLike` in `mySelection()` and `myLike` in `deleteButton()` are not the same `myLike`; they're two separate variables with the same name.  `mySelection()`'s `myLike` can only be used inside of `mySelection()`, and `deleteButton()`'s `myLike` can only be used inside of `deleteButton()`.
2. You have another parameter inside of `deleteButton()`, called `event`, that isn't being used.  Also when you try to call `deleteButton()` inside of `mySelection()`, you only pass in one argument, whereas `deleteButton()` has two different parameters: `event` and `myLike`.

So there are some grammatical issues essentially, and there appear to be a couple of other issues with what you're trying to do in your code, so I really need to recommend that you try to find a tutorial that does more in terms of just taking things one step at a time.  You need to learn about things like scope, global variables, classes, parameters, etc.

But just as far as these two functions are concerned, *in and of themselves*, this should work:

```
function mySelection(myLike)
{
    trace("I select " + myLike + ".");
    deleteButton(myLike);
}

function deleteButton(myLike) {
    trace(myLike + "has been deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressed);
btnDelete.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClicked);

function keyPressed( event:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    var myLike:String;

    if (event.keyCode==49) {
        myLike = "ice cream";
    }
    else if (event.keyCode==50) {
       myLike = "chocolate milk";
    }
    else if (event.keyCode==51) {
       myLike = "cookies";
    }
    else
    {
        myLike = "nothing";
    }

    deleteButton( myLike );
}

// presuming your button instance names are the same as the names in the switch statement 
function onButtonClicked( evt:MouseEvent ):void {
    var deleteThis:String = evt.target.name;

    deleteButton( deleteThis );
}

function deleteButton( myLike:String ):void {
    trace(myLike + "has been deleted");
}
```

This code does not actually delete anything though.  If you want to delete the button that was clicked on try this for the onButtonClicked method:

```
function onButtonClicked( evt:MouseEvent ):void {
    var deleteThis:String = evt.target.name;

    // path to the display list your button is in
    removeChild( evt.target );
}
```